# SQL Server connection timeout error in nodejs mssql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sql-server-2016, tedious, node-mssql

Always getting following error after couple of SQL statement execution.

I am using

```
var sql = require("mssql");
```

> (node:12240) [DEP0064] DeprecationWarning: tls.createSecurePair() is
>   deprecated. Please use tls.Socket instead. warning.js:18 (node:12240)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 2): ConnectionError: Failed to connect to
>   Server-100:undefined in 15000ms warning.js:18 (node:12240) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. warning.js:18 (node:12240)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 4): ConnectionError: Failed to connect to
>   Server-100:undefined in 15000ms warning.js:18

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to server-100:undefined in 15000ms
 at Connection.tedious.once.err (d:\API\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (d:\API\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:634:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

Following is the code :

```
module.exports = function (data) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        var database = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'Server-100',
        database: 'SQLDB',
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
            useUTC: true
        },
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 60000
        }
    });

        database.connect().then(function () {

            var req = new sql.Request(database);
            req.input(data.parameter.Name, data.parameter.DataType, data.parameter.Value);                
            req.execute(data.procedureName).then(function (result) {
                database.close();
                return resolve(result);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                database.close();
                return reject(err);
            });

        }).catch(function (err) {
            database.close();
            return reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

> Exception has occurred: ConnectionError ConnectionError: Failed to
>   connect to 10.0.2.183:undefined in 15000ms
>       at Connection.tedious.once.err (d:\Projects\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at Connection.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at Connection.connectTimeout (d:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:634:12)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

Can you suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score -3):

In the server place use local host and try.

```
var database = new sql.ConnectionPool({
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'password',
        port:"1433",
        server: 'localhost',    //if your connecting to localhost\instance make sure you have the service 'SQL Server Browser' running. 
        database: 'SQLDB',
        options: {
            encrypt: true,
            useUTC: true
        },
        pool: {
            max: 10,
            min: 0,
            idleTimeoutMillis: 60000
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have sql server on different machine

Comment: @FurqanMisarwala then assuming server-100 is your instance name. make sure you have the service 'SQL Server Browser' running

Comment: After 600 call, timeout with IP Address ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 10.0.2.183:undefined in 15000ms

Comment: it doesn't seem likely to me that idelTimeoutMillis would have any bearing on the connection timeout ... or would it? Please can you explain in your answer